# Remote Text Editing: Linux to Linux

Tags: linux

Notepad++ has a great feature where I can edit a file on a remote PC using SFTP.  Notepad++ is only supported on the Windows platform.  I need to use Ubuntu and edit files on a remote PC which has SSH and SFTP support.  Is there a GUI based editor for Linux which does something similar to Notepad++.  Right now I SSH in and use vi.  The amount of editing which I need to do is not a good match for vi.

Comment: Most graphical SFTP clients (like FileZilla) should let you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run ssh with X-forwarding you can launch any GUI application and have it run on the client machine.

```
$ ssh -Y user@server-address
...
$ gedit /some/remote/file
```

I'm not sure what kind of editor you're looking for in-place of vi. As far as I know notepad++ isn't a WYSIWYG editor.

Also, some people do use [vim](http://www.vim.org/) (likely also available on the remote machine) as their go-to editor, though it does have a bit of a learning curve if you're not used to it.